# Move UICollectionViewCell that is currently not loaded

Tags: iphone, swift, collectionview

I'm using Firebase to create a networking app for a client.
For every user, I add an observer to its Firebase property `timestamp`, that means that when the user uploads a status update, the Firebase observer gets triggered so that the users cell in the feed move to the top (every user only has one cell). Here's the Firebase code:

```
Database.database().reference().child(forUser.userID).child("timestamp").observe(.value) { (snapshot) in

        if let timestamp = snapshot.value as? Int {

            if let cell = self.feedCollectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? FeedCell {

                self.feedCollectionView.moveItem(at: indexPath, to: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0))

            }

        }

    }
```

It is though very well possible that I have 100-200 users and maybe the last of them updates his status and has to be moved to the top, even though his collection view cell has never even been loaded.

When I run this, it prints for every visible cell that it is movable and for every invisible cell that it can't access the unloaded cell.

How can I access a cell that has never been loaded and move it to the top?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of moving a cell that may or may not be loaded, you should update the collectionview's datasource by sorting it on timestamp. Then you can call  self.feedCollectionView.reloadData() and it'll place it on the top automatically.